# Add a select a class dropdown in tinymce

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, plugin-tinymce

How can I add add a dropdown/select with pre defined class names into the Wordpress wysiwyg (tinymce advanced) that I can put on different elements?

What I'd like:

1. Add some text or any other element
2. Click the text and click the dropdown to select a class to be added to that element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the dropdown styles we have to use the filter hook `tiny_mce_before_init`. This filter grants developers access to the TinyMCE settings array.

The following example adds custom style options to an existing Style dropdown.

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce_before_init' );

function my_mce_before_init( $settings ) {

    $style_formats = array(                     
            array(
                    'title' => '1/5 Block',
                    'block' => 'div',
                    'classes' => 'col-md-5',
                    'wrapper' => true
            ),
            array(
                    'title' => 'Pull Left',
                    'block' => 'div',
                    'classes' => 'pull-left',
                    'wrapper' => true
            ),
            array(
                    'title' => 'Button R',
                    'selector' => 'a',
                    'classes' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
            ),  
            array(
                    'title' => 'Text Center Green Button',
                    'selector' => 'a',
                    'classes' => 'btn btn-green center'
            ),              
            array(
                    'title' => 'Clearfix',
                    'block' => 'div',
                    'classes' => 'clearfix'
            ),
    );

    $settings['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );

    return $settings;

}
```

You can read more about the tinymce buttons and their uses and hooks from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_buttons,_mce_buttons_2,_mce_buttons_3,_mce_buttons_4).

Comment: What does your code do, how does it work. Why would this solve the issue. Where should it be used. It is all just one big mystery. Please file an [edit] with theses requirements

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PieterGoosen. Explanation added.